# How to suppress launching Job-based Pod again on other node in the case of node failure?

Tags: kubernetes

I am creating a container which is expected to run only once in any case.
Using Job-based Pod, with some settings (job's backoffLimit: 0, pod's restartPolicy: Never), I was able to run it only once when container crashed, but not when the node stopped (e.g. kubelet stopped).

Few minutes after the node stopped, Kubernetes automatically reschedule the Pod on the other node (which is still alive) and the container processes again.

Is it possible to stop this behavior by setting something to Job manifest (or cluster)?

---

Edited:
Actually I am using Java client instead of manifest file, but the resulting manifest will be like this:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  backoffLimit: 0 # never restart
  template:
    metadata:
      name: test
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Never # never restart
      initContainers:
      - name: test1
        image: test1:1.0
      - name: test2
        image: test2:1.0
      containers:
      - name: test3
        image: test3:1.0
```

There are three containers including initContainers, and I want to let them run only once as they process the input data and store them in other containers. However, when the node fails and eviction is performed during the execution of the Pod, k8s recreate it on other nodes and it will cause duplicate processing.

Comment: Hi @Daigo, please include your manifests in your original post, also if possible, please explain in more detail what you want to achieve, I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information and my poor English, I have added some information.